# Running a java program from shell script with redirection

Tags: java, shell, io-redirection

I have a java program (Main.java, uandf.java and node.java), where the Main program takes in the contents of a input file and does stuff. For my assignment, I have to write a shell script that compiles and runs the program, but the input file have to be redirected in to the shell script: i.e. shell_script.sh < file.

Is there a way for the contents of the file to be passed in to the java program as a command line argument?

What I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

javac -O Main.java uandf.java node.java
java -cp Main "$1"
```

I am running the script with `./shell_script.sh < filename`

The main method in the java program:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
     String[] array = args[0].split("\n");
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a strange and non-canonical thing to do, but yes:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
javac -O Main.java uandf.java node.java
java -cp . Main "$(cat)"
```

Normally you would instead have your Java program read from `System.in` (as if from the keyboard), and just used:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
javac -O Main.java uandf.java node.java
java -cp . Main
```

When running `./shell_script.sh < filename`, reading from `System.in` via `Scanner` or `BufferedReader` would then return data from `filename`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is strange, but our professor wants the assignment done like this, even though we write our code in eclipse and never did anything like this before :/
Thank you for the help! ^^

Comment: If you provide complete answers for an assignment, you are preventing the OP to actually learn.

Comment: Start a SocraticOverflow where instead of direct answers to direct programming questions, you can post discussions designed to let people arrive at the answer themselves